Docker: can't open files from mount
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API which produces html documents in the results directory of the docker container. I have used a bind mount so that any files saved to the results directory folder also get saved to a folder on my host so that they can be viewed. However, when I try to open them, I get the error "Access to the file was denied".
How do I make it so that any files to the results folder, or any files saved in any subdirectory of the results folder are accessible on the host.
If I inspect the files, it would be appear that the files are being saved as the container root instead of my user:
ls -l results/1.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3688 Aug 17 14:53 'results/1.html'

However, if I set my appuser
USER appuser

or
user: '1000:1000'

I get the error message:

realpath(Api.dll) failed: Permission denied

Dockerfile:
# Build builder image
# Get dotnet 8 SDK image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy
COPY ./Api.sln ./
COPY . ./

# Build, test and publish
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore
RUN dotnet test
RUN dotnet publish API/API.csproj -c Release -o out --no-build

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime-env

# Create a user to run the application under.
RUN addgroup --gid 1000 appuser && adduser --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --disabled-password appuser

# Set the work directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN chmod -R 760 /app

# Copy the published application output from the builder image to the runtime image
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

## Stops the app from running with "realpath(Api.dll) failed: Permission denied"
# USER appuser

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]

Compose
services
  api:
    image: <image>
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./mnt/results/:/app/results/

Thanks,
Adam

When you ls -l results on the host, the root user is the host's root. Your container is running as the host's root and creating files as root in the results folder. You could sudo ls -l results. After USER appuser, you attempt to run API.dll but it is owned root and appuser (760=rw-rw-rw-) doesn't have x. I think you could chmod -R o+rx /app and then USER appuser and then the app should run as appuser. You will then see -ls -l results owned by 1000:1000 and so you will still need sufficient permission to access the files (albeit they won't be root).
